# Mysql Query match to check if query has been updated

Tags: mysql, antlr4, analysis

I am trying to match two MySQL Queries (*for now, the target is "Create VIEW"*) to analyze if the result of execution would result in the same effect to Database.

The source of the queries is not the same, making the syntax across the queries inconsistent.

To further simplify the question, let me add more details:

- Let's say there is an already existing **View** in the database.
- This **View** was created using a **Create VIEW ...** SQL statement.
- There is a possibility that the **Create VIEW ...** statement get's updated, hence to reflect the changes in the database currently this statement is executed at the time of migration.
- But, I want to avoid this situation, if the statement **Create VIEW ...** will result in the same structure as of the existing **View** in the database, I want to avoid executing it.
- To generate the **CREATE VIEW** from database I am using **SHOW CREATE VIEW...** (*comparing this with the query originally used to create the VIEW*).
- The primary restriction is I need to make this decision only at the time of migration and cannot presume any conclusions (*say, using git diff or commit history...*).

I have already done some search to look for a solution for this:

- Found no direct solution for this problem (*like a SQL engine to which I can feed both queries and know if the result would be the same*).
- Decided to Parse the queries and to achieve that ended up looking into ANTLR (*also used by MYSQL WorkBench*)
- ANTLR's approach looks promising but, this will require an extensive rule-based parsing and creating a query match program from scratch.
- I realized that just parsing queries is not enough, I have to create my own POJOs to store the atomic lexers from queries and then compare the queries based on some rules.

Even if I could find predefined POJOs, that would allow to quickly create a solution for this problem.

Comment: This question is way too broad for Stackoverflow. You should start your implementation and ask specific questions about details (e.g. ANTLR4 or SQL problems). What you are after is to diff SQL code, something what MySQL Workbench does for synchronisation. And this is a complicated task, but you can at least look at the [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/grt/src/diff/grtdiff.cpp#L53) for ideas. Note: WB converts the SQL code into an internal tree representation first (the GRT tree).

Comment: @MikeLischke I did start the implementation and went with ANTLR to parse the queries; while doing so I found that the cases to cover are huge in number (*like MySql allows alias's for functions to maintain backward compatibility*), which made me realize it's better to grow on an already devised solution.
Btw, thanks for your input, I'll look into the code to see if it is useful.